# How to get the previous application's page url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink

There are two different applications named AppOne and AppTwo, also AppTwo has a  `html` file called `b.html`.

How can I back to the AppOne page when user triggers the link which exists in the AppOne page, like this:

```
<a href="AppTwo/xx/xx/b.html>click me</a>
```

Comment: that would be one way

Answer (score 0):

you can write a static link in b.html to refer to the first application the same way you wrote the above link

or you can use javascript to know the caller and redirect to it

```
<script>
    var referrer =  document.referrer;
    location.href = referrer ;
</script>
```

Comment: Thx for suggestion, But I don't know which appone page should be back, so It cannot make a static link in b.html. Also I have tried the latter one, but it gets me to the intermediate jump page.